# Getting 500 Internal Server Error with Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement basic functionality of the Stripe API, I get 500 Internal Server Error for some reason when I require the Stripe.php file that you have to require...When I comment the require out the error goes away but obviously I can not use the API then..

Basic require...shows error in the Modal Log

```
require_once('/php/Stripe.php');
```

I checked the server error and it gave me this back

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Stripe needs the Multibyte String PHP extension.' in /php/Stripe.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /home/stripepost.php(4): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /php/Stripe.php on line 13
```

This all comes from just requiring the file..

Comment: A 500 error in PHP means _go check the web server's error log_. The error will be more detailed there.  Always when developing or testing code, enable PHP's error display. At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and the fatal error will be printed to your screen.

Comment: Your fatal error is that it can't find that file because the absolute path does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer I didn't have the mbstring enabled on my server...whooops

Comment: If you use composer, the dependencies will be checked - https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/composer.json
Also, see https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 0):

Is your 'Stripe.php' file really located in '/php' or is it in a folder called 'php' local to your code?

Current code:

```
require_once('/php/Stripe.php');
```

I think the problem is this. You probably mean to use something relative to your code base. Like this:

```
require_once('./php/Stripe.php');
```